# no namespace infront of an integer

Tags: namespaces, integer, int, std

So my question is: Why isn't it necessary to write

```
std::int a;
```

This is annoying me for such a long time. Is it because there is no influence of the API of the namespace std?

Comment: why would you want to write `std::int a`?

Comment: there is no reason to write this. I just would like to know for my own interest why this is not possible. Because I can write `std::uint16_t` as well.

Comment: Because the language contain the default types like `char`, `bool`, `int`, `float` and `double`, moreover namespace `std` contain other typed aggregated like `list`, `vector`, `set`, `map` and some others

Answer (score 0):

If you want to declare a variable inside a namespace (for example std), you should do it like this:

```
namespace std {
    int a;
}
```

And later, if you're not using `using namespace std` (as you may) you should use the variable like this:

```
std::a;
```

Comment: Yeah, that is clear. But I was wondering if the int is defined in the namespace std or not. So propably it isn't but why and where is it defined. i mean you always can use `std::string` or `std::vector<int>` or `std::list<int>`

Comment: It is defined in the namespace std. You can use std::string if you use `include<string>`, and anybody may use `std::a` if they include a header with the fragment `namespace std { int a;}` inside. But I don't recommend you use namespace std for your own libraries.

Comment: I know what you want to tell me. But that isn't my question.